# Lisa draws a regular polygon and cuts out a regular pentagon with the same length from it. Find the perimeter of the remaining shape.

Tags: geometry

Lisa draws a regular hexagon of $11$ cm and cuts out a regular pentagon with the same length from it. Find the perimeter of the remaining shape.

A) $88$ cm

B) $99$ cm

C) $110$ cm

D) $121$ cm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You lose $11$cm from losing the side, but gain $4*11=44$cm from the cut out of the pentagon.

Comment: I couldn't understand. What's 4 doing here?

Comment: @zarrar Draw out the shape as they did.

Comment: I worked it out. Is that 110 cm?

Comment: @zarrar Make sure to take into account that you lose $11$ cm from removing a side.

Comment: I did like this. 66-11 (by removing one side) = 55 cm. The perimeter of new hexagon + pentagon  = 55+55=110 cm. Is the true?

Comment: @zarrar You don't add the entire pentagon, as one of the sides of the pentagon is the side that you removed.

Comment: That means 55+44=99 cm. I think that's the right one? Is it?

Comment: @zarrar It is. Generally, you should try to draw these problems out to see what is going on.

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I have a problem in another one. One kg of dried figs costs Rs.11.25 while one kg of fresh figs costs Rs.9. A farmer has 20 kg of fresh figs. What is the difference in weight of the farmer's figs before and after they are dried?

Comment: @zarrar Generally, try to look up your problem online to see if there is an answer. If you don't find one, ask the question on stackexchange. I would suggest taking the tour for more information.